# Customizing UISegmentedControl in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

Here is my problem. I am customizing a UISegmentedControl by setting the background and divider images in the following way:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

When I try to make the 1st segmented selected within `viewDidLoad`

```
self.segmentedControl.selectedIndex = 1;
```

I get the following weird thing:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is a bug and how could I provide a bug report? If not, what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Do I gather correctly that your control looks fine when you manually tap one of the segments after your view has loaded? Or does it always look as in your first image?

Comment: You are right. It looks like this the very first time the class is loaded and the value is manually set. Then later in the application if the user taps on any of the segments, then it looks fine. Also, if there are two segmented controls and user changes value of the first and I programmatically change the value of the second due to some logic, then it looks fine too. I am using iOS 4.2 SDK on Snow Leopard.

Comment: It seems that the control is using the wrong divider image at the start (it's using the one for unselected/unselected instead of unselected/selected). At what point exactly in your application's lifecycle are you setting the appearance of the UISegmentedControl?

Comment: I am setting the appearance in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: I've used this myself before without problems. The segmented control's value was loaded programmatically at the start from NSUserDefaults, yet I haven't encountered this before. While it is possible that there is a bug in the SDK, I would think that there would be a lot more people with this problem in this case. It may help if you can post more code.

Comment: Untested: you could try not having any selected while loading and then, on `viewWillAppear`, "selecting" the one you want.

Comment: I have tried that too, and it doesn't work!

Comment: I agree that this must be a bug. I've set the appearance in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and used stretchable images but am having the same problem. Tried all the solutions below but no success.

Comment: There seems to exist a similar (but another) bug in iOS 6. When the view is first loaded (if using two segments) the view uses the wrong divider image until you programmatically switch to another segment and back again. This doesn't work if you do it in viewWillAppear, but it does work if you do it in viewDidAppear!

Comment: *Addition to above comment* this issue appears when the control state is set to disabled.

Comment: I've done this and it worked fine. Are you using resizable images? I used single pixel wide resizable images and it worked with no issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing some tests and trying several different locations for the customization, I believe this may indeed be a bug.

Even with a very simple straight UISegmentedControl, this is what I get (using Xcode 4.3.1, iOS 5.1):

> After launching and selecting the middle element in code:
>   [image: After launching and selecting the middle element in code]
>
> After user-clicked away and clicking back on middle element:
>   [image: After user-clicked away and clicking back on middle element]

I used 3px wide images for the separators and 1px wide images for the backgrounds.

*Edit*:
I think I found a workaround: try queueing the instruction to select the element, rather than  executing it in viewDidLoad, like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
   self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
});
```

On my example above, queuing that instruction makes it work just fine.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer because it kinda works for me.
All these controls are in my settings page, and I have another control to change the theme. So, if I change the theme (different set of images for the segmented controls), I show a loading screen after which the view is shown again and it is broken. But if I move to another view (at this time the settings view is deallocated) and if I come back to the settings view (where it is allocated again) the segmented controls appear fine.

Comment: where did you put this statement?

Comment: this worked for me, but I'm not sure I like having to queue it, seems like a hack

Comment: did anyone file a RDAR for this?

Comment: this approach is working but it breaks my tableview.I do not get any rows if i call this as last  in viewdidload.

Answer (score 4):

I think your image CapInsets is incorrect, please double the example in  http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

here is some codes from the Tutorial for quick reference:

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve the problem after I did a lot of experiments.

Your problem is from the incorrect width setting for the segments.

First point - we need to do UI customization before setting the width of individual segments.

Second point - we need to count the width of the divider(s) and it is very important. When we do customization, the divider(s) is part of the UISegmentedControl elements. The divider is not an overlay. We should count the width of the divider also.

Third point - when we use the set width method for the segments, the segment width does not need to include the divider's width.

If you follow the above rules, you would get a perfect customized UISegmentedControl.

Comment: How will I get the width of the divider? And does the width of all the segments need to be the same?

Comment: The width of the divider is the actual width of the divider image. The width of each segments can vary. When doing UISegmentedControl customization, you need to do a better calculation.

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't see how this is supposed to work. At no point in my do I set the segment's width manually. The UIAppearance proxy is supposed to take care of all this. @user403015 could you please elaborate on how you got it to work?

Comment: If I am using resizable images, how on earth does "calculating widths" make any difference?

Did anyone get this fixed btw?

Comment: Just calculate divider and save calculated value to file?

Comment: Does divider image bloats the margin of segments?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set resizable images?

For example:

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentSelectedImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This is how I am creating my images.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try initializing your appearance settings earlier than `viewDidLoad`. In the demonstrations I've seen this was usually done in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, though any point prior to loading the nib containing the customized views should work.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work! I am thinking it might be a bug with the SDK.

Comment: Someone has downvoted our answers **without inserting a comment**. I'm really disappointed for this. I set +1 for you. Cheers.

Comment: Did you see my comment? Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by different way. I just commented this line of code:

```
self.pageController.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

And segment bar changed it view to normal state.

Comment: How is this relevant to the OP's issue?

Comment: I had the same problem, and it`s solved by the way i pointed in message

Comment: Can you edit your answer to make a clearer link to the question in that case?