# UISegmentedControl does not respect divider images set for UIControlStateDisabled

Tags: ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol, uiappearance

I'm using the new `UIAppearance` API in iOS 5 to style a `UISegmentedControl` with custom graphics. I need to be able to set some segments to be disabled at times during execution, but the `UIAppearance` methods don't seem to allow me to set a divider image for the `UIControlStateDisabled` state.

I'm calling:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:disabledSelectedImage
                                    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateDisabled
                                    rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

where `disabledSelectedImage` is a resizable image from this resource:

[image: disabled-selected-image]

Yet when I set the left segment to be disabled (`[UISegmentedControl setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:]`), the result is this:

[image: UISegmentedControl UI glitch]

You can clearly see that the `UISegmentedControl` has defaulted to use the `UIControlStateNormal`-`UIControlStateNormal` divider image.

It seems perfectly happy for me to set a background image using `UIControlStateDisabled`

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:disabledImage
                                    forState:UIControlStateDisabled
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

(and respects the image I supply while in the disabled state) but not a divider image. Has anyone come across this or found a solution?

Comment: This looks like a bug. I think you should file it at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: @jfortmann I think you're right, I've changed the flow for now to remove segments instead of disabling them. Seems there are quite a few bugs in the `UIAppearance` API for `UISegmentedControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've decided that this must be an iOS bug and have filed a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/11031502) with Apple. My solution to the problem for now is to remove segments, rather than disabling them.

Comment: I did [the same](http://openradar.appspot.com/10999544) earlier this week. Glad to see I'm not the only one.

Comment: @CoryKilger I did notice your report as well while building this segmented control, but luckily it didn't affect me because I didn't need to select the second segment first. I'll repost yours through radar so hopefully we get some more attention.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an ugly workaround but i managed to fix it with the following until apple fixes it itself.

First you need to subclass UISegmentedControl and add the following:

```
@implementation MJSegmentedControl

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSInteger cachedIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    self.selectedSegmentIndex = cachedIndex;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a need to use the appearance controls of iOS 5 yet but if all else fails you could add the resizable image as a child of the segmented control to cover up the ugliness.  It's a hack, but it may work and will be relatively forwards-compatibile.  Just be certain to set the autosizing masks appropriately.

Comment: I plan to use the customised segmented controls throughout the app, possibly with different numbers of segments/positions etc. So unfortunately I don't think it will work for me.

Comment: Why not make your own subclass of UISegmentedControl that automatically adds the resizable image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it really seems to be a bug. However I've found a solution (a workaround).

I've used XIB file with a controller. In XIB file segmented control was just placed and all of the customisations were done in `-viewDidLoad` method.

Then I've created a UIView subclass which represented entire view in the XIB. It made possible moving all view customisation code to the `-awakeFromNib` method of this UIView subclass. After moving this code the divider images were set properly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Fernando in this thread:
[Customizing UISegmentedControl in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114186/customizing-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-5)

You can try to dispatch your UISegmentedControl settings on the main queue via:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    // disable part of the segmented control
    [self.eventScopeSegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:2];
});
```

I did this in viewDidLoad and it worked fine for a while but when my app is really busy at startup, this doesn't always work.  I'm guessing there's a race condition that may still revert any settings you made when the appearance proxy goes to work.

I added another ugly hack to make this call in viewWillAppear (after the call to super:viewWillAppear) with a flag (set from viewWillLoad) to ensure this only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a pretty simple way to get this done. The current behavior is obviously a bug so this is not an ideal solution but simply a workaround that works beautifully. Namely, use an additional UIView as a "disabled visual cue".

The general steps:

1. Add a UIView as a sibling to the UISegmentedControl. Ensure the UIView is in front of the UISegmentedControl
2. Apply the desired color and a transparency to the UIView to match your app skin
3. Move the UIView to be exactly on top of the UISegmentedControl
4. Shape the UIView to have the exact size top of the UISegmentedControl
5. Apply a rounded corner to the UIView to mirror the exact shape of the UISegmentedControl

When the UISegmentedControl is supposed to be disabled, simply show the UIView and disable the user interaction on the UISegmentedControl.

When the UISegmentedControl is supposed to be enabled, simply hide the UIView and enable the user interaction on the UISegmentedControl.

**In both cases do not change the UISegmentedControl.enabled property.**

Note that it seems like a lot of steps but all of this can be coded in so to add support for disabling your custom UISegmentedControl becomes pretty much a 1 liner after you add this to a configure segmented control method.

Here is how my custom segmented control looks when applying this solution:

**Enabled Segmented Control**

[image: enabled segmented control]

**"Disabled" Segmented Control**

[image: disabled segmented control]

Here are some code snippets of interest:

**Shape the UIView to match the UISegementedControl (load time configuration)**

```
  UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = ...
  //Segmented Control disabled visual cue view
  UIView* view = ...

  //Step #2       
  view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];

  //Step #3 and #4
  view.frame = segmentedControl.frame;

  //Step #5
  view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  view.clipsToBounds = YES;

  //Ensure this is disabled by default
  view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

**Enable/"Disable" UISegementedControl (runtime state change)**

```
BOOL segmentedControlEnabled = ...

if(segmentedControlEnabled) {
  segmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  view.hidden = YES;    
} else {     
  segmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  view.hidden = NO;
}
```

That's it.

-