# How to style a UISegmentedControll?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am creating an iOS app using Rubymotion.
In one of the views I am using a UIsegmentedcontroller and it works fine.

How can I customize it. I need to use custom background image for the whole background (this does not work) and images for each button (this works).

*This is my current code:*

```
options = ["Selected","Unselected"]
    segment = UISegmentedControl.alloc.initWithItems(options)
    segment.addTarget(self, action: :'open:', forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged)
    segment.frame = [[0, 0],[320, 40]]
    segment.segmentedControlStyle = 7
    segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segment.setImage(button, forSegmentAtIndex:0)
    segment.setImage(button2, forSegmentAtIndex:1)
```

*I tried with this code:*

```
segment.apperance.setBackgroundImage(button, forState:UIControlStateNormal , forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)

segment.setBackgroundImage(button, forState:UIControlStateSelected , forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

*But if I do I get this error:*

```
undefined method `appearance' for #<UISegmentedControl:0x9655a90> (NoMethodError)
```

*I tried without the appearance too but then I got:*

```
undefined method `setBackgroundImage' for #<UISegmentedControl:0x946db70> (NoMethodError)
```

**Update**

*I tried this and no image is shown on the background:*

```
segment.setBackgroundImage(background, forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  **`setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:`**

It sets  the background image for a given state and bar metrics.

You can see the details in [Apple.Developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW38)

**Sample Code:**

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114186/customizing-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-5)

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this (see updated question) but the image does not show on the background. Is there a way to remove the border around the buttons?