# UISegmentedControl divider bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm encountering a strange bug with my UISegmentedControl dividers. When I drag my finger away, the segment loses its Highlighted State image, but the divider retains it. I need to drag about 100px away for this to occur.

Down, on target:

[image: Down on target]

Down, finger dragged away from target:

[image: Down off target]

Given that 0 means normal state, 1 selected state, and 2 highlighted state; I have all the proper divider images and I set them for each case, that is:

```
00, 01, 02
10, 11, 12
20, 21, 22
```

Everything else works fine, if I tap and hold on target there is no issue. I don't expect users will be tapping and dragging, but I'd rather have this resolved. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114186/customizing-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-5

Comment: Sorry but it's not a duplicate. That person was having issues with dividers after programmatic selection. My dividers work upon creation and with programmatic selection, the only issue is that when holding down on the segment, and then dragging the finger far away from the tap target, the dividers confuse their states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to provide divider images for "11" and "22" states because logically you can't have 2 adjacent selected segments or 2 adjacent highlighted segments. Well, only if tapping adjacent segments simultaneously will highlight them both, but not likely.

Therefore you should have following divider images:

```
00, 01, 02  
10, --, 12  
20, 21, --
```

In addition, you should also have 3 background images for all 3 different states (Normal, Selected and Highlighted). The reason for these background images as well as how to create them I have explained [here](http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol) (in that explanation I have used only 2 background images for Normal and Selected states, but if you want to use Highlighted state then you need to add 3rd background image).

Here is the diagram that shows how these images are used in UISegmentedControl:
[image]

And then set them using following appearance methods:

```
// Set background images
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:background_image_normal
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal
                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:background_image_selected
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected
                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:background_image_highlighted
                            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Set divider images 0=Normal 1=Selected 2=Highlighted
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_00
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_01
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_10
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_02
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_20
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_12
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider_image_21
              forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to manually subclass UISegmentedControl, and override it to make sure the divider state is properly 'cleaned up' when the UIResponder events are called.  It could be that the segment is anticipating the touchesMoved event to occur within the same boundaries as the initial touchesBegan.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the 
UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted

```
// Set background images
UIImage *normalBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-background-unselected"];
UIImage *selectedBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-background-selected"];
[self setBackgroundImage:normalBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:normalBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage
                forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Set divider images
UIImage *buttonImageLeftSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-left-selected"];
UIImage *buttonImageNoneSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-none-selected"];
UIImage *buttonImageRightSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented-right-selected"];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageNoneSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageLeftSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self   setDividerImage:buttonImageRightSelected
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
      rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```